# Bug on homescreen on ELL - not showing what action or username

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, question-lists

I just went to ELL.SE and saw this on the homescreen:

[image]

<sub>^On chrome</sub>

I reloaded the page, and it persisted, so I went to Firefox:

[image]

Same bug.

Comment: Maybe it's because it was migrated?

Comment: Yes. And the person that wrote it originally, doesn't have a user on ELL. There is nothing to show.

Comment: @Oded So why not auto-create an account? If the user doesn't like it,they can delete it afterwards.

Comment: That argument goes both ways. Why create it, if the user wants to, they can do that later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is by design. The [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97959/the-existence-of-a-solution-the-uniqueness-of-the-solution) was migrated from another site (English SE) and the author has no account on ELL, so there is no profile link to click on.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is there isn't yet a user to show. The post was migrated from another site, and the user who last modified the question/answer doesn't have an account on the other side.

To fix this 'bug', the system could attribute the last change to the Community user if there isn't an account available to show.

Comment: If it were attributed to the Community user, if the OP registered on the site, they would not be able to take ownership of the post.

Comment: I didn't propose to make the post owner Community, instead the migration could be attributed to that user, or 'just show' the Community user name in the home screen (just like you would do with an anonymous edit).